# Content script not being injected in options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "js" : ["js/detector.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

**detector.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    console.log("Injection");
    ....
```

I have this setup in my extension. The `detector.js` listens for certain keypresses and performs desired action. I want it to work on the options page too so that I can help out users. But it doesn't work there. I have the `console.log` at the very top of the file. But, I see no logs in the options page.

**My question:**
How do I get my content script to work on the options page?

**UPDATE:** Now I am in some trouble. If I include `options.js` file, that handles the options page, and `detector.js` file (the content script) together in options page like:

```
<script src="../js/options.js"></script>
<script src="../js/detector.js"></script>
```

then they both are interfering with the `chrome.storage`. I could of course put a check in the detector.js like `if(!data_already_modified) then do this;`but it is a kind of hack that I would put as my last resort. So, my question:

**I want my content script to run in the options page, as it would on a normal webpage. Is there a better way than just to link the content script as a `<script>` element?**

As simple as that.

**UPDATE:** Emrys commented, "the option page works as a normal webpage, including a script with  works exactly as on a normal webpage". I cannot validate this claim, as ever since I asked this question, I managed to split my content script into two separate files - one for keypress manipulation, the other for data storage handling. That way I could include the former file into `options.html` through a `<script>` tag without any conflicts.

Comment: Hum, adding a script balise with the option page script as source ? Content Script are used for inject code in page wich are not on you're possession or you can't modify source.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin But I want to do that. There's tons of functionality in the content script (> 1000 lines) and I can't replicate it in another file

Comment: Yes I imagine... So add `<script src="detector.js"></script>`. I don't understand your problem

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin omg haha :) i didn't think of that for the past week i have been trying.  Thank you! voted to close the question.

Comment: Haha :-) No problems, it happen to every body :-P

Comment: Such a question should not be _closed_, and @EmrysMyrooin should **learn to stop answering in comments**. Please make that an answer (at least after you established it helped).

Comment: @Xan Okey done. I have commented because I wasn't sure if I well understood his question.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin And that's why I edited my comment to include the part in the parentheses. Your "make sure I understand the question" comments are legit - just don't leave questions hanging with 0 answers if you helped.

Comment: What is exactly the problem ? Interfering with the `chrome.storage`in to different script is not a problem. At least if you don't manage the value in both of them. Perhaps some pieces of code could be more explicit ?

Comment: And the option page works as a normal webpage, including a script with `<script>` works eaxctly as on a normal webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link the javascript file of your Content Script in your Option page HTML file like this :

```
<script src='detector.js'></script>
```